# Can somone help me remove these bumps?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, smooth

I've tried to smooth it out numerous times but it just creates creases or more bumps. I'm totally stumped and have no clue how I can smooth it out so its a nice geometrical helmet. can anyone help me do this?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: did you try sculpt -> flatten with a big radius?

Comment: i'll try it now :^)